# Filtering message handlers on asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I developed an API and need to protect it . 
I need to secure most of the methods in security1 and some with security2.
I developed two message handles implement the both securities. 
I face a problem , the two handles executes sequentially with all the requests . 
How I can filter the handler up to the request in a cool way .
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: what is security1 and security2?

Comment: Are security1 and security2 in different Routes ? If they are, you can just configure the handlers in the route definitions

Comment: Actually security 1 is basic authentication , and security 2is HMAC authentication , I want to authenticate some of the post request with the first and some with the HMAC security .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two authorize filters and apply where you want them to be.

```
public class MySecurity1Attribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // Do your security 1 stuff here and return true if authorized
    }
}

public class MySecurity2Attribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // Do your security 2 stuff here and return true if authorized
    }
}
public MyController : ApiController
{
    [MySecurity1]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
    }
}

public MyOtherController : ApiController
{
    [MySecurity2]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a clean solution.